# ¿Como cambiar un valor Booleano en un template de django 3?

Tags: python, django, web, django-models, django-templates

Estoy iniciando con python y django y tengo un modelo o tabla llamado cliente y una de sus columnas es el estado el cual en la base es un valor booleano, pero al mostrarlo en el template quisiera que se modifiquen esos valores, algo como activo e inactivo, espero me haga entender.

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar un if tag por ejemplo

```
{% if cliente.estado %}
  Activo
{% else %}
  Inactivo
{% endif %}
```

De esta forma decides que valor mostrar al usuario dependiendo del valor almacenado.

Comment: precisamente eso hice, lo siento estoy empezando y no domino el tema, te agradezco igual por responder.

Answer (score 0):

En django los template solo se utilizan para mostrar información, no se permiten cambiar valores.

Para modificar los datos tienes que hacerlo en una vista, que generalmente obtiene los valores del template por formulario y modifica el modelo si todo es correcto.

Luego con ese formulario puedes modificar los datos de ese Boleano.

[image: Django mvc]